# Date conversion from string

Tags: mysql, sql

I have run a query

```
select STR_TO_DATE('March-2008', '%M-%Y')
```

I got output:

```
February, 29 2008 00:00:00
```

Why it is not `March, 01 2008 00:00:00`

mysql 5.5 
[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8006f/1)

Comment: It set day as 0 - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8006f/3

Comment: Perhaps `select date_format(STR_TO_DATE('March-2008', '%M-%Y'),'%Y-%m-01') as d ;`

Comment: `select STR_TO_DATE(concat('1-','March-2008'),"%d-%M-%Y") as d`

Comment: `Unspecified date or time parts have a value of 0, so incompletely specified values in str produce a result with some or all parts set to 0:`. See [STR_TO_DATE(str,format)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date). Try: `SELECT DATE_ADD(DATE(STR_TO_DATE('March-2008', '%M-%Y')), INTERVAL 1 DAY);` [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9eecb7db5/478).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @splash58 and @wchiquito(`answering` from you `comments`);

Unspecified `date` or `time` parts have a value of `0`, so incompletely specified values in str produce a result with some or all parts set to `0`

See [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

Query:

```
select day(STR_TO_DATE('March-2008', '%M-%Y'))
```

OutPut:

```
0
```